# Is screen-width calculated before or after "rotation" in landscape mode (media-query)?

Tags: css

Say I have the following

```css
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width:1024px) {

.some_class
}
```

is the max-width calculated before or after the landscape mode? E.g say I have a 780x1024 tablet would that query trigger when using the tablet in landscape-mode?

Comment: Its the width for the current orientation. So yes, it should trigger.

Answer (score 1):

> screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width:1024px)

This is a match condition, both `screen`, `orientation` and `max-width` must match before rendering the inside css. So, yes, the CSS content is applied after both conditions match, independently from the declaration order.

Comment: My question is, if the width is based on the orientation e.g if a screen of 720x1024 have a width of 720 or 1024 when in landscape

Comment: `orientation: landscape` checks if the browser viewport is wider than tall, so when the page loads the viewport `width` (supposing a fullwidth state) is `X`, this is the first thing checked, then it checks if `X` is greater than `Y` and return `true`. Then the second condition `max-width` is parsed and it checks if `X` is also lower than or equal to `1024` if this is true the whole [media condition](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#media-conditions) is applied.